# Data Validation from seperate google sheets workbook

Tags: google-sheets

i am trying to create a dropdown menu in a g-sheet in workbook A that looks at a list in a sheet in a seperate workbook B.

i know i can do this by creating a new sheet in workbook a and using the import range function to link to the range in workbook b and then data validate it to the sheet i want to have the dropdown menu in.

my question is can i do this dropdown menu without creating a new sheet in workbook a and using the importrange function. can i just data validate it directly to the sheet in workbook b? both workbooks are in the same folder in the drive.

thank you in advance. no end of googling this has helped

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I have used when working with Sheets, is utilizing the "QUERY" Function.

For example Sheet1 is my primary workbook and need data from the second workbook called "Sheet2" to be placed under the primary:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!$A$2:$H$7, "select B, MAX(D) group by B order by MAX(D)")
```

The example query is an edit from the official documentation [a link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)!